# RabbitMQ consumer utilization zero under high load

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

We use spring amqp based listener container - with about 40 consumers, prefetch count 1. The message ttl is about 60sec before it gets to dead letter queue.

The operation performed by each consumer is a database update - which is slower than the rate at which the messages arrive into the queue.

After sometime, the number of messages pile up in queue the consumer utilization is down to zero. I was under the impression that the consumers are blocked on database. However if I look at the thread dump all the consumers are in wait state on rabbit mq - no messages are being processed.

```
    "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-7" #51 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fcb01ad0800 nid=0x58f7 waiting on condition [0x00007fcae5af1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000854c30c8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:390)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1097)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1100(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The queue also gets into flow state.

Not sure why the queue message processing is stopped. I understand publish to it being restricted.

Any suggestions would help.

Comment: I'm not specifically familiar with Spring AMQP, but a prefetch count of 1 sounds extremely low (a different library that I have used in the past has a default of 50, for example). Was there a reason for this, and have you experimented with different values? Increasing the prefetch count is typically how you'd increase individual consumer utilization, since you are essentially giving each consumer "more work" to do. Also, what volume of messages (e.g., per sec) are we talking about here?

Comment: The message rate is > 700 per sec. I did experiment with prefech - however the queue shut off is the problem. Also I have only one TCP connection to rabbit for all the channels i have. Is that a limiting factor?

Comment: In my experience a single TCP connection is usually sufficient. What is the average size of these messages? Are you dealing with a single RMQ instance, or a cluster (and if so, is the queue mirrored across one or more nodes?). Are your RMQ instances disc nodes, or RAM nodes? Is the queue persistent? Also, have you read this blog post? http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/04/14/finding-bottlenecks-with-rabbitmq-3-3/ There is quite a lot of useful information as to what might be causing the flow-control mechanism to activate.

Comment: Another thought - does your database use any sort of locking mechanism for these updates? I'm wondering if the number of consumers you have is part of the problem -- if they are all trying to obtain the same sorts of locks simultaneously, you could negatively impact overall message throughput compared with a smaller number of consumers.

Comment: Thanks. I think the combination of the problems you mention exists.Also i think that if the message ingest rate is high for a queue, all the resources are spent dealing with publisher, leaving consumer dry - may thats what is happening. I will work on making the processing faster anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm never sure how to answer on "suggestions" on SO, so I'll suggest :)

Here are couple of suggestions:

- increase the number of consumers
- increase prefetch limit

Now, I can't tell you to what values, exactly, this has to fine tuned. Also you can try with one of these thing or both. Maybe [this article](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/04/14/finding-bottlenecks-with-rabbitmq-3-3/) can give you a rough idea to on how to start (i.e. what values).

Additionally you could also scale it up, so mirror the queues to couple of more nodes in the cluster, and consume the messages from there.

Also check [this article](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/10/06/new-credit-flow-settings-on-rabbitmq-3-5-5/). Credit flow looks like something you could also try, as well as message paging.